# Computing adjoint w.r.t. hermitian inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given the Hermitian inner product on $\mathbb C^2$
$$ \langle (x,y),(z,w) \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 10 & 1-3i \\ 1+3i & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \bar z \\ \bar w \end{bmatrix}, \tag 1$$ 
and I am asked to compute the adjoint of the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 3i \end{bmatrix}$. Do I need to diagonalize the matrix in $(1)$ to find $A^\dagger$? Is there a quicker way I'm not seeing?

Comment: Check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233182/the-adjoint-of-a-linear-operator-with-respect-to-an-inner-product